# I need to store some integers in array and print them with symbols of alphabet

Tags: c, arrays

The problem is; I'm doing an assignment. And I need to read some values for an array which sizes of rows and columns (2-D array) given at first. After reading values I need to use Bubble Sort algorithm to sort them in descending order. The problem is; I need to assign a character (from A to Z) to every integer value (naming/classifying it) and sort the integer value with a character I assigned to it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IL 81
#define PARTI 26

        ///Variables:
int partiSayisi;

/**This variable is going to take a value between [0,81]
  *so it will be ROW of the array when I read values.*/   
int plakaKodu;

/**This is equal to 'plakaKodu', and I'm using it as the index,
  *if I use the actual variable as the index, it isn't working. (Not
  *sure why...)*/
int plakaKoduIndex;

/**The 2D array which holds variables I read from input.*/
int oySiniflama[IL][PARTI] = {0};

char partiIsimleri[26]= 
 {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q',
                'R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

 ///Function Prototypes:
//------------------------------------------//
void oyAl(int partiSayisi, int plakaKoduIndex); //Input Routine
//-------------------------------------------//
void ilOyGoster(int plakaKoduIndex, int partiSayisi); //Output Routine
//-------------------------------------------//
/**Bubble Sort Function:*/
void bubbleSort();
//-------------------------------------------//

   ///Functions.:
//-------------------------------------------//
void oyAl(int partiSayisi, int plakaKoduIndex)
{
    int i;
    char j='A';

    for(i=0; i<partiSayisi; i++)
    {
        printf("%c Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: ", j);
        scanf(" %d", &oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i]);
        ++j;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------//
void ilOyGoster(int plakaKoduIndex, int partiSayisi)
{
    int i;
     for(i=0; i<partiSayisi; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %c Partisi: %d oy.", partiIsimleri[i], 
        oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i]);

    }
}
//-------------------------------------------//
void bubbleSort()
{
    /**Bubble Sort icin: */
    int i = 0, j=0, m=0, gecici_int;
    char gecici_char;
    for(m=1; m<(IL*PARTI); m++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<IL; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<PARTI-1; j++)
            {
                if(oySiniflama[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    if(oySiniflama[i][j] < oySiniflama[i][j+1])
                    {
                        gecici_int = oySiniflama[i][j];
                        oySiniflama[i][j] = oySiniflama[i][j+1];
                        oySiniflama[i][j+1] = gecici_int;
                    }
                    if(oySiniflama[i][j] < oySiniflama[i][j+1]);   
                    {
                        gecici_char = partiIsimleri[j];
                        partiIsimleri[j] = partiIsimleri[j+1];
                        partiIsimleri[j+1] = gecici_char;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//For control.
        for(i=0; i<IL-1; i++)
        {
            if (oySiniflama[i][PARTI-1] > oySiniflama[i+1][0])
            {
                gecici_int = oySiniflama[i][PARTI-1];
                oySiniflama[i][PARTI-1] = oySiniflama[i+1][0];
                oySiniflama[i+1][0] = gecici_int;
            }

            if (oySiniflama[i][PARTI-1] > oySiniflama[i+1][0])
            {
                gecici_char = partiIsimleri[i];
                partiIsimleri[i] = partiIsimleri[i+1];
                partiIsimleri[i+1] = gecici_char;
            }
        }
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------//
```

Expected input and output:

**Expected input**

```
//TEST
A Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 3082
B Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 2556
C Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 1900
D Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 2581
E Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 2000
F Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 1255
G Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: 12
```

I did input screen as instructed; entered a char (from A to Z) for classifying that integer value; now here comes expected output:

**Expected Output**

```
A Partisi   3082
D Partisi   2581
B Partisi   2556
E Partisi   2000
C Partisi   1900
F Partisi   1255
G Partisi   12
```

How can I assign a char to an integer, and sort them as shown above using Bubble Sort as my sorting algorithm, and using Functions and Arrays (Assignments rules are strict.)? (And I can't use structs...)

~Thanks for taking the time...

(PS. Thanks for explaining to me about posting rules. This is my first time writing a question here, sorry for writing a non-understandable question... I edited it as soon as possible.)

(PS. [ @John Bode ] Thanks to you for taking the time. Even if I wrote an unclear question at the first time... Now I edited it so others can get help if they need a similar problem, too.

Comment: You want the code you show here to be English. Because it is you who wants a quick and good answer.

Comment: If sorting is not your problem, please keep it out of your question and show code which only demonstrates your problem. The idea is described here: [mcve].

Comment: Please provide textual information in textual shape, not as picture of text. That failitates working with the info and indirectly helping you.

Comment: Oh sorry; new to this site... I didn't have time to organize my code :(. I will re-organize question tomorrow. Thank you for informing me about the posting.

Comment: @Yunnosch | Is my question clear and descriptive now? I want this comment to help others who have a similar problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want a way to store the character value with the integer value *without* using the `partiIsimleri` array, correct?

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use a `struct` type:

```
struct labeled_value {
  int value;
  char label;
};
```

You'd declare `oySinfiflama` as

```
struct labeled_value oySiniflama[IL][PARTI] = {{0,0}};
```

You'd change your input routine to use the following:

```
for(i=0, j='A'; i<partiSayisi; i++, j++)
{
    printf("%c Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: ", j);
    scanf(" %d", &oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i].value);
    oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i].label = j;
}
```

You'd change the guts of your bubblesort as follows:

```
if(oySiniflama[i][j].value < oySiniflama[i][j+1].value )   /* Azalan sirada siralamak icin, > u < e cevir. */
{
    struct labeled_value gecici = oySiniflama[i][j];
    oySiniflama[i][j] = oySiniflama[i][j+1];
    oySiniflama[i][j+1] = gecici;
}
```

IOW, you do your comparisons on the `value` member, but you swap the entire `struct` value.  This allows you to get rid of the `partiIsimleri` array altogether, so you can drop that part from your `bubblesort` routine completely.

And then, your output code will read:

```
for(i=0; i<partiSayisi; i++)
{
    printf("\n %c Partisi: %d oy.", oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i].label, oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i].value);
}
```

**EDIT**

> Bu the problem is; I can't use structs. As I said in information; I only can use basic features of C and some of the intermediate ones (Functions & Arrays). Rules are strict, that is why I am struggling...

Oh for ████'s sake, `struct`s ***are*** a "basic feature of C".  Slap your teacher for making this assignment harder than it needs to be<sup>1</sup>.

Okay, well, then you are stuck using a separate array to maintain the labels, and it will need to be a 2D array as well (so that you have a unique label element for each number):

```
char partiIsimleri[IL][PARTI];
```

So your input routine will look like:

```
for(i=0, j='A'; i<partiSayisi; i++, j++)
{
    printf("%c Partisi'nin oy sayisini giriniz: ", j);
    scanf(" %d", &oySiniflama[plakaKoduIndex-1][i]);
    partiIsimleri[plakaKoduIndex-1][i] = j;
}
```

You can tighten up your bubble sort:

```
if(oySiniflama[i][j] != 0)
{
    if(oySiniflama[i][j] < oySiniflama[i][j+1])   /* Azalan sirada siralamak icin, > u < e cevir. */
    {
        gecici_int = oySiniflama[i][j];
        oySiniflama[i][j] = oySiniflama[i][j+1];
        oySiniflama[i][j+1] = gecici_int;

        gecici_char = partiIsimleri[i][j];
        partiIsimleri[i][j] = partiIsimleri[i][j+1];
        partiIsimleri[i][j+1] = gecici_char;
    }
}
```

That is, instead of two separate loops to swap the integers and the labels, you can do both operations in the same loop.  You really don't want to add any more loops to a bubble sort.

---

1. Joking.  Do not actually slap your teacher.  Even if they *really* deserve it for making you pretend you're writing Fortran 77.

Comment: A very good opinion. Thank you! Bu the problem is; I can't use structs. As I said in information; I only can use basic features of C and some of the intermediate ones (Functions & Arrays). Rules are strict, that is why I am struggling... :( Anyway thanks for effort your answer taught me something new. :)

Comment: :) Thank you very much, @JohnBode ... I argued with my teacher about this but whatever... I was curious about making a 2D char array; because I tried it with 1D char array I declared, but it just sorts out alphabet :P. Now I'm going to edit my post, so others will understand it too. Thanks for taking the time :)...